# Why CDN link for Bootstrap does not work in Heroku

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, cdn

When I add Bootstrap via CDN and run in through Heroku does not work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Instead if I add Bootstrap locally works fine.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Why doesn't the CDN link work in Heroku?

Comment: Check out if your site under HTTPS, some browser like chrome don't allow HTTP content in HTTPS sites. If you have no idea about it, just change the href to `//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: @pupboss thanks for the answer!!! Problem solved